# Calculating luminance in $\rm{cd/m^2}$

Tags: image-processing, color, image

Let's say I have an image of the following transparent material through which light is passing,

[image]

I want to calculate the luminance in units of $\rm{cd/m^2}$.

What I did is

```
ao = Import["image path"];
l1 = ColorSeparate[ao,"L"];
MatrixPlot[ImageData[l1], PlotLegends->Automatic]
```

However, the outcome is not what I expected. Is there any way to get the luminance in $\rm{cd/m^2}$.

Comment: No, you cannot. Luminance is a physical (or photometric, in fact) quantity, and you cannot calculate it from an image made by an ordinary camera. You need a specialized device, a luminance meter, which is properly calibrated to perform such measurements.

Comment: A camera measures the _incident_ flux ([illuminance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Illuminance) of the camera sensor), not the _emitted_ flux (emitted by the transparent material in all directions). The unit of illuminance is the [lux](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lux) and can be measured by a lux meter. A $\text{lux}=\text{cd}\cdot\text{sr}/\text{m}^2$  is not the same as a $\text{cd}/\text{m}^2$; there is a factor of a steradian connecting the two. In any case, you'll need a lux meter to calibrate your camera before being able to map pixel intensities to illuminances.

Comment: @Roman     Actually, this image has been taken from an imaging colorimeter and I want to be independent of the software used by the camera provider. So, basically, this image is taken by a camera that is calibrated with a lux meter.

Comment: @Domen Actually, this image has been taken from an imaging colorimeter and I want to be independent of the software used by the camera provider. So, basically, this image is taken by a camera that is calibrated with a lux meter.

Comment: If you've calibrated it with a lux meter, then you know the correspondence between pixel values and lux meter readings? If yes, then please provide an example of such calibration data.